# How frequently are the Azure Storage Queue metrics updated?

Tags: azure-monitoring, azure-diagnostics, azure-storage-queues

I observed that it took about 6 hours from the time of setting up Diagnostics (the newer offering still in preview) for the `Queue Message Count` metric to move from 0 to the actual total number of messages in queue. The other capacity metrics `Queue Capacity` and `Queue Count` took about 1 hour to reflect actual values.

Can anyone shed light on how these metrics are updated? It would be good to know how to predict the accuracy of the graphs.

I am concerned because if the latency of these metrics is typically this large then an alert based on queue metrics could take too long to raise.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

[Platform metrics are created by Azure resources and give you visibility into their health and performance. Each type of resource creates a distinct set of metrics without any configuration required. Platform metrics are collected from Azure resources at one-minute frequency unless specified otherwise in the metric's definition.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/data-platform-metrics#data-collection)

And ['Queue Message Count' is platform metrics.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsoftstoragestorageaccountsqueueservices)

So it should update the data every 1 minute.

But it didn't. And this is not a problem that only occur on portal. Even you use rest api to get the QueueMessageCount, it still not update after 1 minute:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/resourceGroups/0730BowmanWindow/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/0730bowmanwindow/queueServices/default/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?interval=PT1H&metricnames=QueueMessageCount&aggregation=Average&top=100&orderby=Average&api-version=2018-01-01&metricnamespace=Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices
```

---

```
{
    "cost": 59,
    "timespan": "2021-05-17T08:57:56Z/2021-05-17T09:57:56Z",
    "interval": "PT1H",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "/subscriptions/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/resourceGroups/0730BowmanWindow/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/0730bowmanwindow/queueServices/default/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/QueueMessageCount",
            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
            "name": {
                "value": "QueueMessageCount",
                "localizedValue": "Queue Message Count"
            },
            "displayDescription": "The number of unexpired queue messages in the storage account.",
            "unit": "Count",
            "timeseries": [
                {
                    "metadatavalues": [],
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "timeStamp": "2021-05-17T08:57:00Z",
                            "average": 1.0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "errorCode": "Success"
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices",
    "resourceregion": "centralus"
}
```

This may be an issue that needs to be reported to the azure team. It is so slow, it even loses its practicality. I think send an alert based on this is a bad thing(it’s too slow).

**Maybe you can design you own logic by code to check the QueueMessageCount.**

Just a sample(C#):

1, [Get Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.queueserviceclient.getqueuesasync?view=azure-dotnet)

Then get all of the queue names.

2, [Get Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.queueclient.getpropertiesasync?view=azure-dotnet)

Then get the number of the message in each queue.

3, sum the obtained numbers.

4, send custom alert.

**Original Answer:**

At first, after I send message to one queue in queue storage, the 'Queue Message Count' also remains stubbornly at zero on my side, but a few hours later it can get the 'Queue Message Count':

[image]

I thought it would be a bug, but it seems to work well now.

Comment: Hi Bowman, yes I updated my question after leaving things overnight - it took around 6 hours to reflect the actual total. Now looking for someone how knows what's going on behind the scenes! Thanks for the corroboration.

Comment: @JamesWorld Sorry, your question has not changed when I wrote the answer.

Comment: @JamesWorld Did you just test it to work? My test was invalid before 20 minutes.

Comment: It took ~6 hours to report an accurate number for me.

Comment: @JamesWorld I found that it is fundamentally quite slow (although the official document says it is updated once a minute, it is obviously not). Instead of issuing an alert based on this, it is better to design your own code. I updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah I figured the documentation wasn’t accurate - I’m holding out for an MS insider to explain what really happens... :)

Comment: I meant on here - I’ve not opened a support case for this at the moment.

Comment: @JamesWorld Hi, If my answer helps you find 'How frequently are the Azure Storage Queue metrics updated', can you accept it to end this question?:) If you have any update on this question, I will update my answer.

Comment: I have upvoted it, because it helped corroborate the situation - thanks for that. I won’t accept it though because it does not explain definitively how metrics collection timing for queues is implemented. It offers similar empirical observations to those I made in the question. I also note you didn’t upvote the question :) but that’s completely fine with me.